# Conditional flask Login login_view

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a flask web server, and it uses flask_login for user authentication.

My web server servers both websites and native mobile applications.

I want end-points which serve website (accessed by browsers) to serve login_view when user is not logged-in.

But the end-points which server native applications (android and ios) to respond with HTTP 401 response code.

How can  I set LoginManager.login_view conditionally only on few endpoints

Comment: How do you differentiate between the two types of requests?

Comment: There is no automatic way to differentiate, if thats what you are asking. I was wondering if I can have differnet decorators for two types of end-points.
`@login_required_with_login_view`, `@login_required_without_login_view`

Comment: So they're completely separate endpoints? You can decorate an endpoint with anything you want. If you want two `login_required` decorators that do different things, you can do that.

Comment: Yup, true that I can decorate with whatever decoratorI want. But what do I do to make sure that login_view is set, and reset based on what the end-point is

Comment: One (or both) of your decorators will probably need to handle redirecting to the other URL manually.

Comment: I am confused. From flask_login documentation, a object of LoginMananger is allocated GLOBALLY, and that global object's login_view attribute is set to something. Now I am confused how can I set / reset right before a method is called. Could you give an example. Even if I decorate, with my own decorators, don't they modify the global LoginManager object

Comment: `login_view` is used to redirect. Either you can handle that redirect yourself or you can use blueprints and set different views for each blueprint.